# Visual Studio Linker Error for Debug X86 Build

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, build, linker, x86

Initially I was using PATH 1 under Configuration Properties > Linker > General > Additional Library Directories for build c++ project. But later I changed the path like this PATH 2.

```
PATH 1: C:\XXX\AAA\Android\BBB\CCC\Libs\Debug\x86\
PATH 2: C:\XXX\AAA\Android\Arge\PROJECT\CPP\..\..\..\BBB\CCC\Libs\Debug\x86\
```

If I using the first path, project build will successfully. But if I using second path, get the error message like this:

```
unable to execute command: program not executable
linker (via gcc) command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What is wrong this situation?

Note: I try two path and they are opened the same file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing the second path is simply too long for some tool or the OS to handle properly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I read something about relative path. Is there any setting for debug x86 accept relative path?